# How to give label for map marker in android

Tags: android, maps

I want to display labels for map markers like A,B,C..
[image]

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Either**

use `Title` to `marker` which will add title but the result will not be as you shown in image

**or**

use the different Images which are already labeled ( A,B,C etc) for `marker` , as you shown in your question !